# Trouble calling stored procedure with parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-agent, tinyint

I am trying to update SQL Server Agent schedules using [msdb.dbo.sp_update_schedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187354.aspx), but when I try to call the stored procedure from code I get exceptions.

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException:
> Error converting data type int to
> tinyint.
>
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
> behavior, String method)
>
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

How can I convert a value to a tinyint?

I have tried

```
MyParameter.DbType = System.Data.DbType.
```

but there is no TinyInt available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MyParameter.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Byte;
```

Answer (score 2):

try with

```
MyParameter.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Byte
```

because

```
tinyint is actually
   Integer data from 0 through 255. Storage size is 1 byte.
```